# Trying to get the element to appear once after clicking, but appears more than once

Tags: javascript, css, function

Im trying to get the shapes to appear once after clicking. After 1.2 seconds it appears, then when clicked it disappears, then the whole process repeats. The problem is after a few clicks two shapes appear.

This is the link to the program.
https://jsfiddle.net/EyedFox/w98naLjx/2/

```
function show() {
  var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(colors.length * Math.random())]; // Random color chosen
  var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60); // random x axis margin
  var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80); // random y axis margin

  square = document.getElementById("square");
  circle = document.getElementById("circle");
  var shapeArray = [square, circle];
  var randShape = shapeArray[Math.floor(shapeArray.length * Math.random())];

  randShape.style.margin = randomX + "% " + randomY + "%";
  randShape.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
  randShape.style.display = "block";
  randShape.addEventListener("click", click);

  function click() {
    randShape.style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(show, 1200);
  }
}

setTimeout(show, 1200);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code keep adding click event listener to randShape, but it never cleans them those event. As a result, they keep being added and `click` (and thus `show`) will get executed several times per click. Try to add `console.log('clicked on', randShape);` at the beginning of your click function to see it. If by chance all the `show` execution selects the same shape, you'll see only this one on screen, but otherwise you'll get both.

Your `click` function should look like this:

```
function click() {
    console.log('clicked on', randShape);
    randShape.style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(show, 1200);
    randShape.removeEventListener('click', click); // cleaning after myself ;-)
}
```

(btw `(function() { ... })()` is *not* executed on load, but as soon as it is encountered by the javascript vm)

Comment: Thank you!  

Whats the alternative to this: (btw (function() { ... })() is not executed on load, but as soon as it is encountered by the javascript vm)?

Comment: In your case, a listener event on [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that fixes the issue.

Edited my response based on @autra response

I would probably completely clean the canvas before redrawing:

https://jsfiddle.net/c0L54uk3/

Essentially made a reset function like so:

```
  function reset(){
     square = document.getElementById("square").style.display = "none";
     circle = document.getElementById("circle").style.display = "none";
     randShape.removeEventListener("click", click);
  }
```

And called it at the beginning of the click() function to reset the canvas like so:

```
function click() {
reset();
setTimeout(show, 1200);
```

}

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

## Delegate Events Instead of Registering Them Individually

`addEventListener()` should be outside the callback function (i.e. `show()`). There's an event listener being added to the clicked tag but none of them are being removed. So when the 4th to 7th click occurs, the browser starts slowing down and that `setTimeout` is never 1.2 seconds because it will be cued to fire off which means it'll wait however long then wait 1.2 seconds. As the cue accumulates, the clicks will out race the `setTimeout`.

Register the parent tag, `.container` to listen to the click event event for all of its children tags. This pattern is called [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm). In doing so, you can add the click event to an unlimited number of tags within `.container` using only one event listener instead of one for each shape.

The `#triangle` was never styled so it's an extra invisible div that floats around. In the demo I have styled the `#triangle` and added a `.blank` `<div>` outlined in gold (you can remove the `.blank`).

### Demo

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/y0emfhg6/)

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Reference parent tag
var box = document.querySelector('.container');

function show() {
  // Collect all .shape into a NodeList and convert into an array
  var shapes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.shape'));
  var colors = ["yellow", "red", "green", "purple", "aqua", "chartreuse", "coral", "dodgerBlue", "deepPink"];

  var rColor = colors[Math.floor(colors.length * Math.random())];
  var rX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60);
  var rY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80);
  var rShape = shapes[Math.floor(shapes.length * Math.random())];

  rShape.style.margin = rX + "% " + rY + "%";

  // if #triangle change the border-bottom-color
  if (rShape.id === 'triangle') {
    rShape.style.borderBottomColor = rColor;
    // otherwise change background-color
  } else {
    rShape.style.backgroundColor = rColor;
  }
  rShape.style.display = "block";

}
/* 
Run show()
A setTimeout nor an IIFE is needed to initially run show()
Simply call it.
*/
show();

// Register box to click event...
box.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  // ...reference the clicked tag (i.e. .shape)...
  var tgt = e.target;

  // ...reference the registered parent tag...
  var cur = e.currentTarget;

  /*
  ...if the clicked tag IS NOT the registered parent tag...
  */
  if (tgt !== cur) {
    // ...then hide clicked element...
    tgt.style.display = "none";
    // ...and run show() in about 1.2 seconds
    setTimeout(show(), 1200);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 800px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 34, 85);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
}

#square {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: none
}

#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: none
}

#triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 45px solid transparent;
  border-right: 45px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 90px solid cyan;
  display: none
}

.shape {
  cursor: pointer
}

.blank {
  outline: 10px solid gold
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="square" class='shape'></div>
  <div id="triangle" class='shape'></div>
  
  <!--
  This .blank represents what #triangle was before it
  had any style. 
  -->
  <div class='blank'></div>
  <div id="circle" class='shape'></div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```